# When do we use 2 equals when identifying the value of a variable?

Tags: lua, equals, love2d

I'm learning how to use the LOVE engine, which uses Lua, but this engine cannot identify an error about, you know, if you need to do this:

```
if value=1 then
```

or

```
if value==1 then
```

to the engine identify a variable, so I'm asking this to prevent errors.

Comment: Lua is better than most languages about this, since `value = 1` is not an expression, so it cannot go in an `if` statement. You should have gotten a compile error when you tried to execute that.

Comment: Very unclear what it is you are asking here. The first line of code would cause a syntax error at runtime, crashing your program. `=` is assignment, `==` is equality. [RTFM](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/).

Comment: @NicolBolas - The compilation error is the following: `'then' expected near '='`.  Of course, this is very cryptic for beginner to understand the real reason of the error.

Comment: You can't prevent errors; you have to reduce and manage them. Reading a manual is one way to reduce them. The Lua Reference Manual is concise and straightforward. To manage errors, you can use tools such as compilers, IDEs and tests. `luac` is a compiler that you likely have already. See the tag info pages for [Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/lua/info) and [LÖVE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/love2d/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if value==1 then etc.

As you can read here https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.2 and here https://www.lua.org/pil/3.2.html or just here http://www.google.com/